EU261 compensation rejected
Oct. 3rd flight operated by Ryanair from Eindhoven to Brindisi was delayed more than 2 hours: scheduled at about 17:00, it took off at about 21:30.
In the morning of 3rd the Ryanair flight from Brindisi to Turin had a flame out during taxi and the airport was closed for few hours to allow proper recovery, between roughly 08:00 and 11:00. This presumably caused delays at the airport in Brindisi.
When requesting for compensation according to EU261, I get this notification:


the flight does not qualify for compensation [...] it was disrupted due to unexpected closure of either the runway or terminal building at Dublin Airport which was beyond our control.

Is it a legitimate reason for rejecting the claim?

Could you explain the connection between the flight BDS-TRN in the morning and EIN-BDS in the afternoon? It's not clear how they are related. It's also not clear how DUB is relevant but perhaps that's part of the question.

@Cosmittus the incident in the morning affected a lot of flights in and out of Brindisi for 3 hours, and Ryanair claim that this caused the later delay to the EIN-BDS flight (which was indeed operated by an aircraft which was delayed for 3 hours in the morning for that reason, and never caught up). I think the reference to DUB is just a copy-paste issue from Ryanair.

On the fact of it, it isn't. There is no exception for thing that are “beyond our [the airline's] control”, only for extraordinary circumstances (i.e. things beyond an airline's control that cannot be expected and planned for). Then again, maybe runway closure does count as “extraordinary” and the distinction is moot.

It's probably a legitimate reason.
From AIR PASSENGER RIGHTS – EUROPEAN CASE LAW, bottom of page 14:

Extraordinary circumstance on a previous flight with the same aircraft
In order to be exempted from its obligation to compensate passengers in the event of a long delay or cancellation of a flight, an operating air carrier may rely on an ‘extraordinary circumstance’ which affected a previous flight which it operated using the same aircraft, provided that there is a direct causal link between the occurrence of that circumstance and the long delay or cancellation of the subsequent flight.
Cases C-74/19 Transportes Aéros Portugueses and C-826/19 Austrian Airlines

More specifically, the first decision tells us:

in order to be exempted from its obligation to compensate passengers in the event of a long delay or cancellation of a flight, an operating air carrier may rely on an ‘extraordinary circumstance’ which affected a previous flight which it operated using the same aircraft, provided that there is a direct causal link between the occurrence of that circumstance and the delay or cancellation of the subsequent flight, which is for the national court to determine, having regard in particular to the conditions of operation of the aircraft in question by the operating air carrier concerned.

Checking out the flight history of the aircraft that operated your flight, it was indeed stuck in Bergamo for 3 hours waiting to return to Brindisi because of the airport closure, which of course led to delays for the rest of the flights of the day for that aircraft.
There is one minor issue, which is that the aircraft was then assigned to a flight which was not its original program for the day (as it was scheduled to depart Brindisi before the scheduled arrival of the flight from Bergamo), which means it incurred a larger delay (4 hours instead of 3) from then on, but I don’t think that changes the gist of it. I haven’t tried to find which aircraft was initially scheduled on your flight and what delay it incurred.
Bizarrely the whole “can rely on earlier extraordinary circumstances” does not match my recollection of relevant case law, so there may be conflicting opinions.
As an aside, the second case quoted is an interesting example of someone claiming compensation quite abusively IMHO but still going all the way in claims and appeals.

I believe you are correct, @jcaron. However "...the aircraft was then assigned to a flight which was not its original program for the day ... which means it incurred a larger delay (4 hours instead of 3)" : If an aircraft is delayed 3h by genuinely extraordinary circumstances, but the airline then chooses to reassign it and add 1h or 2h delay to subsequent flights, I would argue that 4h = no compensation but 5h = compensation as it's a new issue. So the incoming flight that day (FCO-BDS) was ~5h late landing and compensation would be due - but not for BDS-EIN in the original question?

@Cosmittus it would really for an arbitrator or the courts to decide, we’re quite far into interpretations here.

You may have a claim but could struggle to be paid
I initially thought @jcaron's answer was correct. On the face of it, airlines are not liable for extraordinary circumstances, and there may be a further waiver for direct causal links.
However, a relevant factor is that the aircraft that caused Brindisi Airport to shut in the first place was operated by the same airline. As has been stated, airframe 9H-QCB operating flight FR8826 suffered an engine fire at BDS during ground roll, resulting in an evacuation and runway closure.
At time of writing, the cause has not been made public. If it is a previously unknown manufacturing defect that might affect other aircraft, it is an extraordinary circumstance. If it can be blamed on maintenance, it is not. FWIW, the Italian government has expressed concern at Ryanair's recent mechanical failures.
If we assume that Ryanair is liable for compensation for the earlier FR8826, and by implication the delay to that flight was ordinary, it cannot reasonably be argued that corresponding delays to other affected flights operated by the same airline somehow become extraordinary.
(Note that this would not apply to other airlines operating via BDS that day. They cannot be held responsible for Ryanair's operations)
I also reference @jcaron's helpful link AIR PASSENGER RIGHTS – EUROPEAN CASE LAW, which on page 11 states

"...events whose origin is ‘internal’ must be distinguished from those whose origin is ‘external’ to the operating air carrier."

...not, you will note, external to the individual flight.
In reaching this conclusion, I have been unable to find a previous, similar case which would offer a definitive answer. If one exists, it may render this answer invalid. However, it is surely the situation that for a claim to succeed, it would need to demonstrate that:

The airline is liable for EU261 compensation for FR8826. This is the assumption. However, if the engine fire is an extraordinary circumstance, this answer is moot and @jcaron's answer is correct.
Flights FR8826 and FR3236 are operated by the same airline. They are: the airline is Ryanair and the flights were both operated by Malta Air. There can be no question over separate subsidiaries or business entities, for example.
The delay to FR3236 and others was directly caused by the engine failure on FR8826 which caused the closure of BDS. This is undeniable. Notwithstanding the confusion over DUB / BDS, Ryanair themselves have effectively admitted as such.
There is nothing in EU261 which limits liability to a single flight. There is no reason to restrict compensation solely to FR8826. If the airline is held liable for a specific incident, it would then be for the airline to show that liability may only be applicable for a single flight, an assertion which is unlikely to succeed considering the case law quote above.

These four points may be relatively straightforward to prove, and EU courts have traditionally taken a broad view on the applicability of EU261.
However, if this genuinely is a novel situation, expect Ryanair to delay, misdirect, mislead, and do whatever they are able not to have the situation tested in court. Also expect them to claim that there was a secondary extraordinary circumstance which takes priority over the primary ordinary circumstance (e.g.: "there was later bad weather which caused the majority of the delay"). If it finally ends up in court, they may settle as late as possible to avoid setting a precedence.
Whether this is something you wish to undertake is entirely a decision for you.
